# ArcGis Server: Separate Virtual Directories for Services?

Tags: arcgis-server, security, iis

This is a Windows system. As we know, ArcGIS Server creates a default 'arcgis' virtual directory in IIS and that becomes the starting point for various services. While that is a convenient 'one size fits all' kind of a solution it doesn't help trying to secure some web Services which should be only accessible from within the intranet while still enabling other Services to be accessible from the outside.

So what we need is a way to create different virtual directories in IIS for the Services which would need enhanced security. If we could create a different virtual directory for a secure Service then we can simply use IIS's domain/ip based restrictions on that directory to limit to only the intranet IPs. *Is that even possible in ArcGIS Servers?*

Perhaps, some other option could be to somehow use URL redirect/reverse proxy or use a Service's own security for some role/user based one--but that would require Active Directory on the server and sounds complicating to setup?

Comment: Thanks. But your link doesn't work? Anyway, I am working on a kind of tedious url write to a virtual directory (which would be ip protected) but not making progress yet...

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha! In the end the solution was quite simple. And I **think** will work?! Here it is:!

1) Disable port 6080 by default outside the intranet. Easy to do in my organization!

2) Create URL Re-write URL in IIS: With a 'wildcard' rule of `*services/CULAND` and Url Redirect to: `http://myarcgisserver:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CULAND` (I am making it 'temporary' for now)

And so anyone outside the network may be able to see the port 80 based URL to /services/CULAND but they can't access it because the direct will be to port 6080, which will be inaccessible outside the network.

I am going to test it further and even use some javascript application for testing.

What do guys say?

Thanks.

Comment: So our IT department finally opened port 6080 for within the intranet and I am able to successfully test the protection. Good! Hope this helps someone.